# Combining several boot floppy disks into one HD floppy

Tags: boot, floppy

I have a bit of an obsession with old operating systems, and while teaching myself to use UNIX and about operating systems I came across Minix 1.1. I want to install this on an old Dell setup, and while I am aware of the program RawWrite for writing floppy images in 32-bit Windows, it seems a bit wasteful to put eight 360KB images (all the required boot disks) onto eight 1.44MB floppies.

**Question**: Is there a legitimate way to combine these to make two bootable 3.5" floppy disks instead of eight? Is there also a way to do this with just one CD?

Comment: Consider donating/uploading your collection of abondonware to this site...http://vetusware.com/

Comment: @moab betaarchive.com is a better choice.

Comment: @kinokijuf better for Beta software.

Comment: @Moab They also have an anormous abandonware collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SYSLINUX's [MEMDISK](http://syslinux.zytor.com/wiki/index.php/MEMDISK) can boot multiple floppy images from a single bootloader, chosen at boot.